# Map of Task and Case

Tags: apex, soql, case, map, tasks

(I believe) I want to create a Map that I need someone's advice on. I want the map to have the key be equal to a Task's CreatedDate and the Value be TWO object's values- the Task's Data and the Case's CaseNumber. This is what I have so far:

```
orderedTaskList1 = [SELECT (SELECT CreatedDate, Comments__c, OwnerId, Subject, Owner.Name, AccountId, WhatId, CreatedById, Account.Name FROM Tasks WHERE Private__c = FALSE AND (Status = 'Completed' OR Status = 'Closed')
                    ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC), AccountId, CaseNumber, Merchant_Number__c FROM Case WHERE AccountId = :strAccountId AND Id IN :accountIds];

        caseTaskMap = new Map<String, Task[]>();

        for(Case c : orderedTaskList1){
            caseTaskMap.put(c.CaseNumber, c.Tasks);
            listOftaskCaseTasks = c.Tasks;
            for(Task t : listOftaskCaseTasks){
                orderedTaskListCreatedDate= t.CreatedDate;
                mapOfDateAndTaskandCase = new Map<Datetime,Map<String, Task[]>>();
                mapOfDateAndTaskandCase.put(orderedTaskListCreatedDate, caseTaskMap);
        }
```

My issue that I am running into is that it is only bringing back ONE CreatedDate. As you can see from the example Case # 00033494 has a different created date but the date is not listed as the key:

```
{2017-07-13 16:28:02={
     00033490=(
           Task:{WhatId=500S0000008l5A3IAI, Id=00TS000000Ul9qEMAR, CreatedDate=2017-07-13 16:31:20, Comments__c=RESPONSE TEMPLATE, OwnerId=00580000003HZZnAAO, Subject=RE: Sandbox: - Olivia Test Case Portfolio Record Type RESPONSE TEMPLATE, CreatedById=00580000003HZZnAAO, RecordTypeId=01280000000BawwAAC}, 
           Task:{WhatId=500S0000008l5A3IAI, Id=00TS000000Ul9q8MAB, CreatedDate=2017-07-13 16:30:18, Comments__c=Olivia Test Case Portfolio Record Type SENT, OwnerId=00534000009QnEtAAK, Subject=Email: - Olivia Test Case Portfolio Record Type SENT TEMPLATE, AccountId=001S000000raQdyIAE, CreatedById=00534000009QnEtAAK, RecordTypeId=01280000000BawwAAC}, 
           Task:{WhatId=500S0000008l5A3IAI, Id=00TS000000Ul9puMAB, CreatedDate=2017-07-13 16:28:30, Comments__c=RESPONSE, OwnerId=00580000003HZZnAAO, Subject=RE: Sandbox: Olivia Test Case Portfolio Record Type RESPONSE, CreatedById=00580000003HZZnAAO, RecordTypeId=01280000000BawwAAC}, 
           Task:{WhatId=500S0000008l5A3IAI, Id=00TS000000Ul9poMAB, CreatedDate=2017-07-13 16:28:02, Comments__c=Olivia Test Case Portfolio, OwnerId=00534000009QnEtAAK, Subject=Email: Olivia Test Case Portfolio Record Type SENT, AccountId=001S000000raQdyIAE, CreatedById=00534000009QnEtAAK, RecordTypeId=01280000000BawwAAC}), 

      00033494=(
           Task:{WhatId=500S0000008lPkSIAU, Id=00TS000000UlRjlMAF, CreatedDate=2017-07-17 18:57:22, Comments__c=TEST COMMENTS, Id=00534000009ceS2AAI, Subject=RE: Sandbox: Wire In -, CreatedById=00534000009ceS2AAI})}}
```

The ideal scenario would be to have a map that looked something like this:

```
Map<TaskCreatedDate, List<AllOfTheTaskInformationAndTheCaseNumberRelatedToTheTask>>
```

I have looked into just putting a field on the Task object that pulls it's CaseNumber but I guess this is not a possibility yet. So other then making a junction object, any suggestions on this map?

UPDATE:

The wrapper class works great and to be able to pull out the values into a list I would like it to look something along the lines of:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!caseTaskMap}" var="taskTime">
    <th colspan="5" id="casenumber">{!taskTime}</th> <!--2017-07-13 16:28:02--><!--PRINTS OUT THE FIRST KEY-->
    <apex:repeat value="{!caseTaskMap[taskTime]}" var="caseInfo"> <!--PRINTING OUT THE FIRST VALUE-->
        <apex:repeat value="{!caseTaskMap[taskTime[caseInfo]]}" var="taskData">
            <apex:repeat value="{!caseTaskMap[taskTime[caseInfo[taskData]]]}" var="task">
                <tr>
                    <td>{!taskData.CaseNumber}</td>
                    <td>{!task.Subject}</td>
                </tr>
            </apex:repeat>
        </apex:repeat>
    </apex:repeat>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an apex wrapper class to hold the info :

```
    caseTaskMap = new Map<String, CaseInfo>();
    for(Case c : orderedTaskList1 ){
        for (Task t : c.Tasks) {
          caseTaskMap.put(''+t.createDate new CaseInfo(c.CaseNumber,t);
        }
     }
```

Wrapper class

```
class CaseInfo {
  String caseNumber;
  Task taskData;

  CaseInfo(String caseNumber, Task taskData) {
    this.caseNumber = caseNumber;
    this.taskData = taskData;
  }
}
```

Comment: Great suggestion. The wrapper class worked great. I will mark correct but I do have a follow up question with pulling the values out in this format. When I do a `apex:repeat` on these values, how would I be able to tap into the second key/value pair? I will update the question with an example of what I am talking about.